# Advanced task formatting in Flower (Celery monitoring)

Tags: python, task, celery, display, flower

I use Flower to monitor my Celery tasks.

I'm trying to change the way tasks are displayed (under the *Tasks* tab) in order for the list to look a bit more "organized". For example, displaying `<list (6 items)>` instead of `[1, 2, 3, ...`.

Unfortunately, [overriding the `format_task` method](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#format-task) has limitations :

- `task.args` and `task.kwargs` are string representations, often truncated,  instead of list/dict
- HTML is escaped for every field except `task.name`
- if the function doesn't return a value, an AJAX error is thrown when displaying the tasks

To get the original `args` and `kwargs` objects back I'm using `eval(task.args)` so that I can iterate through their items afterwards. Evaluating random strings looks a bit unsafe to me, would you recommend a better way than doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to get the task's arguments in `format_task` as objects (lists/dicts etc.) instead of truncated string representations.

The `argsrepr` and `kwargsrepr` parameters of the `apply_async()` method allows to specify custom representations for the task's arguments.

I created a custom *Task* class, overriding the `delay` method like so:

```
import json
from celery import Task

class FlowerTask(Task):
    def delay(self, *args, **kwargs):
        argsrepr, kwargsrepr = [], {}

        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, bytes):
                argsrepr.append("<binary content>")
            elif isinstance(arg, list):
                argsrepr.append("<list ({} items)>".format(len(arg)))
            elif isinstance(arg, dict):
                argsrepr.append("<dict ({} keys)>".format(len(arg)))
            else:
                # Format your args the way you prefer
            
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            # Format your kwargs the same way as above
            # if ... :
            # kwargsrepr.append(...)
        
        # Create the task
        new_task = super().s(*args, **kwargs)

        # Use our representations as JSON
        return new_task.apply_async(
            argsrepr=json.dumps(argsrepr),
            kwargsrepr=json.dumps(kwargsrepr)
        )
```

I then use this class as base for my task using the `base` argument :

```
@shared_task(base=FlowerTask)
def test_task(*args, **kwargs):
    return "OK !"
```

This way, the task's arguments representations are stored as JSON that can be loaded afterwards in Flower's `format_task()` and use them as objects instead of strings :

```
def format_task(task):
    argsrepr = json.loads(task.args)
    kwargsrepr = json.loads(task.kwargs)

    if not argsrepr:
        task.args = "( )"
    else:
        task.args = ', '.join(argsrepr)

    if not kwargsrepr:
        task.kwargs = "( )"
    else:
        task.kwargs = ', '.join(f'{key} = {value}' for key, value in kwargsrepr.items())
    # [...]
```

This way, the args are displayed as such:

> **Args:** `<list (3 items)>, <binary content>`
>
> **Kwargs:** `callback = <function>, items = <dict (5 items)>`